# Ao diminuir a janela do browser a posição dos labels é alterada

Tags: javascript

Criei labels dinamicamente com uma certa posição. O problema é que quando minimizo o browser a sua posição altera. Como posso corrigir isso?

```
    //creation labels
    var labeltemp = document.createElement("Label");
    labeltemp.style.left = x2-10;
    labeltemp.style.top = y2+5;  
    labeltemp.style.position='absolute';

    var number = document.createTextNode(number);
    labeltemp.appendChild(number);

    document.body.appendChild(labeltemp);
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/zy6nLcgL/2/

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta e talvez a solução que irei apresentar não resolva seu problema, mas, lembre-se de adicionar a medida quando for mudar tamanhos e posições. `labeltemp.style.left = x2-10 + "px"; labeltemp.style.top = y2+5 + "px";`

Comment: Usar posição "absoluta" sempre dificulta um resultado bom ao redimensionar a janela do browser.

Comment: As labels saem da posição inicial. A posição deve ser a mesma, mas como a janela fica mais pequena, muda.

Comment: @akm então quando dizes "minimizo" queres dizer "mudo o tamanho da janela"? é que aqui em PT "minimizo" quer dizer fechar, colocar no background. Nesse caso tens de ter `position: fixed;` ou trabalhar com percentagens. Tens um exemplo que possas colocar?

Comment: Exacatamente, quando faço resize da janela.

Comment: Ok, então e quando a janela muda de tamanho queres manter exatamente a mesma posição? ou queres manter uma proporcionalidade entre os labels?

Comment: Defina o tamanho e a posição em porcentagem ao invés de pixels.

Comment: O exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/zy6nLcgL/2/ Neste caso nao consigo mostrar aqui as labels nas posiçoes certas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando um elemento com position:fixed a posição dele é relativa a janela não ao gráfico como você estava esperando.

Fixed é usado quando você que manter um elemento preso a uma posição, por exemplo um cabeçalho que vai ficar sempre no topo mesmo quando você rolar pela página.

[Descrição do fixed no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)

Fiz um exemplo no jsfiddle que fica sempre na posição esperada. http://jsfiddle.net/zy6nLcgL/12/

Answer (score 0):

Quando voce redimensiona o margin e/ou padding esta sendo reajustado.
Voce pode fazer o teste usando: 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Usando position: fixed; vai corrigir para o IE.